# TwitteR setup_twitter_oauth() failing

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I was following the vignette for the package, updated and loaded all necessary packages, seemed like it would be a pretty straight-forward process to authenticate. Instead, I get an error

```
> setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

My paraphrased and redacted program looks more-or-less like this.

```
library("twitteR")
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem") #read this was necessary for Windows machines
consumer_key <- 'abc'
consumer_secret <- 'abc'
access_token <- '123-abc'
access_secret <- 'abc'
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

I read a lot of the other SO questions on this topic, nothing solved my issue (most of them used the old authentication process anyway). I'm trying to create a wordcloud following [this tutorial](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/04/06/using-the-r_twitter-package/).

Comment: This used to work just fine for me, but I just opened my script and received the same error. Are you running R 3.2.1?

Comment: Actually, it seems that the problem is caused by an update to the httr package. An [issue](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/90) has already been created on TwitteR github repo, with a workaround.

Comment: @Molx thanks for the info! the workaround worked perfectly and I have successfully authenticated using the program above

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just (install and) load the package 'base64enc'.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had the identical problem on Linux but not Windows - just loading up the library on the linux box solved it.

Comment: Solved my problem on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do the following settings to make this work

package versions :
 base64enc_0.1-3 httr_1.2.1      twitteR_1.1.8

installed twitteR using command:
devtools::install_github("jrowen/twitteR", ref = "oauth_httr_1_0")

And i had an existing app which didnt work so i went ahead a created a new app on twitter.

This combination works for me

Answer (score 3):

Just check your firewall settings and allow R through.

I tried all the the different solutions mentioned regarding packages , etc. None of them worked. I finally found that it is nothing but a simple firewall issue. I recommend that everybody who faces this issue first check their firewall settings. Make sure that R is added in the list of applications allowed through the firewall. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

install.packages("base64enc") was what solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the suggestions here but surprisingly none worked for me. Somebody could be going through the same situation as I did so I answer with what worked for me- it seems that the problem was with direct authentication, so I followed the following steps(this requires one to have the `openssl` package) installed and loaded along with the `twitteR` package;

Ensure you have created your twitter API and have the consumerkey and consumerSecret codes, and preferably remain logged into twitter with your default web browser

```
packages <- c("twitteR", "openssl")
### checking if packages are already installed and installing if not
for(i in packages){
    if(!(i %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])){
        install.packages(i)
    }
library(i, character.only = TRUE) ## load packages
}

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret) ## do not input the access_token and access_secret
```

This is going to open up your default browser with the successful authentication message. You can close the browser now and continue exploring tweets with R.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problems, and after so many attempts.

I found this issue https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/90, where 'jrowen' suggested a work-around that solved my problem. The issue apparently is caused by the new `httr` package, but the work-around is to install the `twitteR` package from GitHub instead of the cran repository using this command:

```
devtools::install_github("jrowen/twitteR", ref = "oauth_httr_1_0")
```

After this, the problem of OAuth authentication error disappeared. Hope this also works for you.

Comment: @AmitKohli Could you be more specific? What message/output did you see when you tried the one I listed above? And what did you encounter before you tried it?

Comment: I get the same error: `Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'`. Does it make a difference how I answer this question?:`"Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions`?

Comment: @Alex_Feng I finally solved the problem by reinstalling latest dev version of `TwitteR`, latest cran version of `httr`, and latest cran version of `base64enc`. Cheers.

Comment: @AmitKohli thanks for sharing. I think what you did was consistent with what I did. I updated all other packages via cran, and then installed the dev version of TwitteR by the code I listed above (and here as well): `devtools::install_github("jrowen/twitteR", ref = "oauth_httr_1_0")`

Answer (score 1):

Try to regenerate the consumer key and access_token keys. I also faced the similar problem. Nothing resolved my problem. But after I regenerated the keys and used the new keys its resolved and works beauty.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different wireless network (which was less secure) and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding proxy fix my issue
hope this would have some others issue fixed

provided you already have a proxy, then input the following line:

```
proxy_url <- "http://127.0.0.1:61387/"
Sys.setenv(http_proxy = proxy_url, https_proxy = proxy_url, ftp_proxy = proxy_url)
```

note:change the settings to your own

Comment: In my solution, you need a proxy like psiphon, then set its port manually to 61387

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. Then realized that I was not logged into Twitter (from default browser). Logged in to Twitter and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Please check your sentences

Answer (score -1):

The problem for me was that my curl was out-of-date, so it wasn't able to verify the SSL certificate it was receiving. All I had to do is update curl (simply `conda update curl` if you're using anaconda) and oauth worked perfectly after that.