# R telling me i have a fatal error when using setup_twitter_oauth

Tags: r, twitter, fatal-error

I am just learning how to stream tweet via R. The thing is, whenever I use setup_twitter_oauth, R immediately terminates the session saying that a fatal error has occurred with a bomb.
I do not know what is the problem. Maybe it is because when I first used this function, R asked me to choose between two options and i chose the first one carelessly. Here is my code and thanks for your answers.

```
Library(twitteR)

consumerKey<-‘XXXX’
consumerSecret<-‘XXXX’
access_token<-‘XXXX’
access_token_secret<-‘XXXX’

setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey,consumerSecret,access_token,acces_token_secret)
```

I have searched that this is enough. I still new to this and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks

Comment: have you had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128492/twitter-setup-twitter-oauth-failing)?