# R devtools::install_github() error in download: unauthorized

Tags: r, github, oauth, twitter-oauth, github-api

I'm trying to tie R to Twitter and everything I try has been failing. I've been looking at several links including the following: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085128/error-in-check-twitter-oauth-oauth-authentication-error-cant-pass-oauth), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058485/oauth-with-twitter-streaming-api-in-r-using-rcurl), [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085128/error-in-check-twitter-oauth-oauth-authentication-error-cant-pass-oauth)

While those have led to more issues, I'm now looking at the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293325/r-install-github-fails/31294266#31294266) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793863/devtoolsinstall-github-ignore-ssl-cert-verification-failure?lq=1) to try some workarounds. I would have posted my question as a comment to either of these links but I don't have enough rep yet.

When I run the following code, I get the following error

Code:

```
library(base64enc)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
devtools::install_github("jrowen/twitteR", user="MY_USERNAME", password="MY_PASSWORD", ref = "oauth_httr_1_0")
```

Error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.
Please download and install Rtools 3.3 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
Downloading GitHub repo jrowen/twitteR@oauth_httr_1_0
Error in download(dest, src, auth) : client error: (401) Unauthorized
```

Am I just completely missing something here in how to download this dev twitteR package? Does anyone have an idea on how to get past the 401 error?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you install Rtools?

Comment: Didn't think it was needed since I'm not building packages. I will attempt with it.

Comment: Even after installing Rtools and restarting R, I get the same error. As described below, when I leave off the `set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )` I get an error of `Downloading GitHub repo jrowen/twitteR@oauth_httr_1_0
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`

Comment: @JRW there is a difference between **building** and **developing** packages. Building means compiling code. You need this to install any package that has compiled code. One thing to be aware of when installing Rtools is to [fix your path](https://stevemosher.wordpress.com/step-six-fixing-your-path/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed and sourced [R tools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) in the session you are referencing above? You aren't getting a certificate error (were you before?) which suggests you don't have a certificate server you're running under as was the issue in some of your linked posts.

I would suggest the following steps to find your issue.

You may need the httpuv package which can be downloaded sourced with

```
install.packages('httpuv')
library('httpuv')
```

Sometimes the twitteR package needs an older version of httr to work correctly, depending on jrowen's (and hadley's) updates.

You may try installing the older version of httr

```
 devtools::install_version("httr", version="0.6.0", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

and restarting R and then trying your install again. Note that if you are on a 64-bit machine, you will probably have to install the most recent version of httr first, then install the older version.

Comment: I will install and source Rtools and try that. As I mentioned to @Roman, I didn't think it'd be needed since I'm not actually building packages. I've gotten every certificate and authentication error that users in my posted links have ran into. Also, I tried to install the older httr using the code you provided and I'm also getting a `Error in download(bundle, x$url, x$config) :   client error: (401) Unauthorized` error just with this.

Comment: Now with leaving out the `set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )` piece and trying your install of httr after installing Rtools, I'm getting an error of `Downloading package from url: http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/httr/httr_0.6.0.tar.gz
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`.   Leaving that piece off as well takes me back to an error of `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates` in twitteR install